# Oracle standby licence

Tags: oracle, license, standby

We're planning to buy new *Oracle Database Enterprise Edition* licence. We have two servers (Live and standby).

Our standby server should be configured as a physical standby, and will be used only in case of disaster.

According to [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_standby_database_licensing.htm) we should buy licence for both servers.

But do we need to Active Data Guard licence? Is it used buy the physical standby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: no.

Active Data Guard is an optional feature that allows you to open the standby database in read-only mode while applying logs from the primary. If you need the standby database only in case of disaster, then you don't need to buy this option.

Comment: Thanks that so clear. Some time i query the following views on the standby database, `V$ARCHIVED_LOG`, `V$LOG_HISTORY`, `V$ARCHIVE_GAP`, `v$dataguard_status`. Does that need the active data guard?

Comment: No, you can query them without it.